# Large app size due to images. How to compress .PNG images?

Tags: android, image, png, compression

I am developing an app which has a lot of images to work on due to which the size of my app has become very large. I want to compress or something like that to reduce the size of app. Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.png`-files which are placed in the `res/drawable` are [automatically optimized](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Bitmap) when compiling your app:

> **Bitmap files may be automatically optimized with lossless image
>   compression by the aapt tool during the build process.** For example, a
>   true-color PNG that does not require more than 256 colors may be
>   converted to an 8-bit PNG with a color palette. This will result in an
>   image of equal quality but which requires less memory. So be aware
>   that the image binaries placed in this directory can change during the
>   build. If you plan on reading an image as a bit stream in order to
>   convert it to a bitmap, put your images in the res/raw/ folder
>   instead, where they will not be optimized.

That being said, you have some more options to try. There is a good talk on this topic from Google I/O 2016 called ["Image Compression for Android Developers"](https://youtu.be/r_LpCi6DQME), which outlines the possibilities, explains their up and downsides and gives some general best practices.

---

If the size of your application is to high to be published on the market, you'll can either

- ship your app without the images and load them from the internet to the phones SD-card when the app is first started
- Use Androids own [APK Extension Files](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html), which is basically the same but you don't have to do everything yourself.

Answer (score 5):

Use [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) or [posterizer](https://github.com/pornel/mediancut-posterizer) to reduce size of PNG images (these tools are lossy, but give significant savings).

You can also optimize them with [PNGOUT](http://advsys.net/ken/utils.htm), which is one of the best lossless optimizers.

I've written [Mac GUI](http://pngmini.com) for those.

Comment: @Kornel does pngquant still work? just tried with the Pngyu GUI and the images are not being displayed on my phone, only in emulator.

Comment: @MrCharli3 Yes. For Android support (preserving of the custom chunks) make sure you have pngquant compiled with libpng 1.6 or newer (`pngquant -h`). I don't maintain pngyu. Official OS X builds are definitely OK.

Answer (score 3):

Always use PNG (.png) images.
And compress it online by uploading your images to

https://tinypng.com/

Simple and sober, always work. You are welcome. :)

There is also a better way to use AndEngine, it saves you from making layout for each phone. And there is no need to use different images for different dpi phones.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use 9-patches for backgrounds? Also you can use imagemagick or anything similar to compress a batch or images.

Comment: I am using .png images in my project. I have seen imagemagick on web but unable to find the command to reduce the image memory size. Can you help me to find out?

Comment: you have to recompress the image using a lower quality

Answer (score 2):

1. Try and use ".png".
2. Use 9-patch images for backgrounds.
3. If you have title bars, headers with vertical gradients, always use 1-pixel width gradient images. This is a super saver.
4. If you manage to get hold of Photoshop, they have the option to save images for web/mobile devices. Helps in making really small sized images with good quality.
5. If u r supporting multiple devices, maintain different versions of the images only for those that are really necessary.