# create graphics in android in a productive manner

Tags: android, user-interface

how to create graphics in android in a productive manner? What are the best practices?" Let's say I'm doing a GUI for multiple devices and I use different density.
Which solution is the best?

1. Putting graphic in hdpi folder and allow android scaled it to the appropiate density?
2. Make my own graphics for mdpi, ldpi and hdpi.

What are your experiences with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that delivering your application with already scaled images (e.g. having ldpi, mdpi, hdpi) is the better approach.

In my first application, I also just added the hdpi images and thought Android would scale them. There are three problems with that:

1. Sometimes, the scaling looks awful or just plain wrong
2. Scaling does of course also add a performance-overhead.
3. **Older devices with lower RAM ran out of Memory** when they had to scale large images

The only reason *against* using multiple images for different densities is, the APK size. Note at this point, that the [`aapt` tool will compress PNG images automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7913138/large-app-size-due-to-images-how-to-compress-png-images), when an APK is build.

Comment: Yes. It's always better to have different images for different screens. But that at the same time makes testing on multiple devices as a prerequisite. You can't always guess how a drawable will perform on different screen.

Comment: @MogamboKhushHua that's a general Android problem. There is no *one device* like with iOs. Still, having one Device for each density tends to give reproducible results.